# How to inside template check if dictionary's size is larger than 0 and if it is larger that 0 to fetch first key value pair?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have passed from view dictionary to template page. How to inside template check if dictionary's size is larger than 0 and if it is larger that 0 to fetch first key value pair ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% if some_dict %}
    Some (k, v) - {{ some_dict.items.0 }}
{% endif %}
```

Note that Python dicts are unordered, so there is no "first" k-v pair.

And are you sure template is a good place for this logic? I am not.